# Check on runtime if textfield contains a number

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to figure out how i can check on runtime whether a number is being entered on a textfield and i want then to execute a Backspace to delete it on its own. My code is 
    `@FXML
    public void onKeyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        if (!(event.getText().matches("[a-z]"))) {
            event.consume();
        }
    }`

I dont understand why it's not working. Maybe i dont understand the concept of changing something on runtime. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2991463/javafx-improvements-in-java-se-8u40.html?page=4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36436243/2991525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this (FX11 Only)

```
    //check if character typed is a number
    if (event.getCharacter().matches("[0-9]"))
    {
        event.consume();

        //move caret back one step as we do not want the typed digit
        //and want the caret to remain after last entered text
        textField.backward();

        //delete the typed digit
        textField.deleteNextChar();

    }
```

Note this uses event.getCharacter() instead of event.getText().  For me getText() is always empty,as in this link:

[JavaFX KeyEvent.getText() returns empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839896/javafx-keyevent-gettext-returns-empty)

Not also if you wish to go your original route of checking if it's not equal to a-z remember to account for A-Z as well.  Or convert the character to lower case before checking as matches is case specific.

FX8 Only

```
if (event.getCharacter().matches("[0-9]"))
    {
        event.consume();

    }
```

Comment: This doesnt work at all.  textField.deleteNextChar(); returns a boolean which i doesnt work on runtime.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#deleteNextChar-- .  As you can see from the link above that deleteNextChar returns true if it deleted the character false if it didn't.  I have tested the code in FX11 and it works as you described how you wanted it to work.  I suspect you didn't even try the code.

Comment: Just tried with FX8 and yes it doesn't work in that environment.  In FX8 just consume the event under getCharacter() and it will work.  See edited answer.

Comment: No i tried the code but it didnt do the job i described. I managed to do it another way with TextFormatter.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't realize the code wouldn't work with FX8 and you hadn't specified a version, anyway I updated my answer so that there is code that works with FX8.  Note the FX8 version does not work in Fx11 and vice versa.

Comment: Oops , my bad you're right. I ended up doing it by passing a filter but your code works too thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing its because you are checking a-z when you should be checking 0-9.

Edit: Oops, you're right I missed the !.
As to it being runtime, aren't all events runtime?

Comment: Even if i said 0-9 it doesnt matter because it's not running on runtime. And btw the code is good doing its job haha u must have missed the ! which means not in java. So im basically saying if it doesnt match - > consume